# Override laravel's 5.2 authenticate method in AuthController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm still very noobish with Larvel, so i can't figure out how to do this:
I'm stuck at the login system. I'm trying to understand how i can prevent inactive users to use the application.

### Edit

With inactive users i mean those users which has the record field 'active' on 0. So i need to implement a check which verifies the mail and the password and also the active field

I've made the tables and the auth system, and as written in the documentation, I've placed this method inside my AuthController:

```
public function authenticate()
{
   dd('hi');
}
```

Well it completely gets ignored. It seems like it never gets triggered. Am I missing something?

My controller looks like the original Laravel's 5.2 AuthController except for the method before. No other changes has been made, since according to the documentation no other changes are mentioned...

### My tests:

I've also searched for a method called authenticate. But no methods where found (using php storm). So my question is:

If it's a trait, isn't supposed to have that method declared? So i can override it just by declaring a method with the same name?

### Important files:

#### Routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove the Auth routes but before that run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal. Copy the auth related routes and stick them in your routes file.

Change the controller in each of the routes to point to your own AuthController in your application.

Next, include the following 2 traits into your controller (top of the page) plus 2 classes;

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and then include the traits in the top of your class;

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

as it stands, the auth functionality should still work as normal.

Then, alter the login method to accept an active flag. Add the following to your new controller;

```
/**
* [login description]
* @param  Request $request [description]
* @return [type]           [description]
*/
public function login( Request $request, $guard )
{
    $this->validateLogin( $request );
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ( $throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts( $request ) ) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent( $request );
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse( $request );
    }
    $credentials = $this->getCredentials( $request );
    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->attempt( [ 'active' => 1 ] + $credentials, $request->has( 'remember' ) ) ) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated( $request, $throttles, $guard );
    }

    // check to see if they can login without the active flag
    if( Auth::guard( $guard )->attempt( $credentials ) ) {
        // log them back out and send them back
        Auth::guard( $guard )->logout();
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput( $request->only( $this->loginUsername(), 'remember' ) )
            ->withErrors([
                'active' => 'Your account is currently not active',
            ]);
    }
    if ( $throttles && ! $lockedOut ) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts( $request );
    }
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse( $request );
}
```

using the traits in your own controller should give you more flexibility in the future.

regards

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I'll implement it this way!

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

If you type php artisan route:list you see when login by post method, user post their info account to login action in LoginController. So, I've solved the problem by override login method in Auth\LoginController as below:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $credentials['active'] = 1;
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent guest users (not authenticated) to access certain routes, you should protect those routes in your `routes.php`:

```
// All the routes inside the group are accessible for logged in users only
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('myroute', 'Controller@action'); 
});

// For routes accessible for everybody
Route::get('login', function(){
    return View::make('login');
});
```

Comment: Hi! I think I've missed the point in the question. Just edited. What I'm trying to do is to perform a third check upon the login. Which is the active field of the record. Not sure if this check has to be done upon the authentication or i just have to retrieve the user data after the authentication and block him there...

Comment: Ah I see. Did you remove the traits `use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;` from the controller? I have the exact same controller from here https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users -`authenticate` method is called

Comment: I've tried that before, and i get this error:
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController does not exist.

I think is somehow related to the routes but i can't figure out what's wrong..

Comment: Can you also post your `routes.php`?

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

I've managed to do this by myself. Not sure that is the proper way, but anyway it works.

I've decided to create a middleware that after the successful login, checks that the user 'active' field is 1. If not it redirects to a specific page.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //  If the user is not logged in
    if(!Auth::user()){
        return redirect('login');
    }
    //  If the user is inactive
    if(!Auth::user()->active){
        return redirect('inactive');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```